# How can I solve the runtime error I'm having while trying to download the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu, linux

I've installed core-geth successfully and started downloading the Ethereum blockchain on Ubuntu (20.04.02 LTS), to an external SSD, with the following command:

```
sudo geth --syncmode fast --cache 256 --datadir /my/ubuntu/directory
```

I was previously able to download around 30GB of the blockchain, had an I/O issue with my postgres server, deleted it all and started over. On the second attempt of running the command above, I successfully download roughly 10GB of the blockchain and then receive the following error:

```
INFO [04-01|13:55:14.592] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet... 
INFO [04-01|13:55:14.599] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [04-01|13:55:14.599] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [04-01|13:55:14.601] Set global gas cap                       cap=25000000
INFO [04-01|13:55:14.601] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=38.00MiB dirty=64.00MiB
INFO [04-01|13:55:14.601] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/my/ubuntu/directory/geth/chaindata cache=128.00MiB handles=524288
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.207] Opened ancient database                  database=/my/ubuntu/directory/geth/chaindata/ancient
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.220] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: 7280000 Petersburg: 7280000 Istanbul: 9069000, Muir Glacier: 9200000, Berlin: 12244000, YOLO v3: <nil>, Engine: ethash}"
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.294] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/my/ubuntu/directory/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.294] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/root/.ethash                     count=2
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.296] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=1 dbversion=8
ERROR[04-01|13:55:15.300] Invalid block total difficulty RLP       hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" err="rlp: non-canonical integer (leading zero bytes) for *big.Int"
ERROR[04-01|13:55:15.300] Invalid block total difficulty RLP       hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" err="rlp: non-canonical integer (leading zero bytes) for *big.Int"
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.300] Loaded most recent local header          number=3914289 hash="5a2bec…510a11" td=385112087024004810425 age=3y9mo4w
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.300] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0       hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" td=<nil>                 age=51y11mo4w
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.301] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0       hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" td=<nil>                 age=51y11mo4w
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.302] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=12153782
ERROR[04-01|13:55:15.302] Truncating ancient chain                 from=3914289 to=0
ERROR[04-01|13:55:15.303] Invalid block total difficulty RLP       hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" err="rlp: non-canonical integer (leading zero bytes) for *big.Int"
ERROR[04-01|13:55:15.303] Invalid block total difficulty RLP       hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" err="rlp: non-canonical integer (leading zero bytes) for *big.Int"
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.303] Loaded most recent local header          number=3914289  hash="5a2bec…510a11" td=385112087024004810425 age=3y9mo4w
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.303] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0        hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" td=<nil>                 age=51y11mo4w
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.303] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0        hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" td=<nil>                 age=51y11mo4w
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.303] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=12153782
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.307] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=0
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.307] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.308] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.331] Allocated fast sync bloom                size=127.00MiB
ERROR[04-01|13:55:15.334] Section processing failed                type=bloombits error="block #24576 [32aa8325…] not found"
WARN [04-01|13:55:15.336] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-04-01T12:20:32+0000 age=1h34m43s
WARN [04-01|13:55:15.336] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-04-01T13:42:52+0000 age=12m23s
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.336] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.1-stable-c2d2f4ed/linux-arm64/go1.16
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.438] New local node record                    seq=13 id=d066354df5c85f9e ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.441] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://4b5995de053f02c13896857649f7a3aa8d6a45d73c646d940348515bb0bfd97415b06dd73960c7404506245895c4a93cfbe574caa5455708cf6403a867260c96@127.0.0.1:30303
INFO [04-01|13:55:15.444] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/my/ubuntu/directory/geth.ipc
INFO [04-01|13:55:17.856] New local node record                    seq=14 id=d066354df5c85f9e ip=90.196.48.17 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [04-01|13:55:18.282] Mapped network port                      proto=udp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
INFO [04-01|13:55:18.783] Mapped network port                      proto=tcp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
INFO [04-01|13:55:23.336] Initializing state bloom                 items=2892346 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=8.002s
INFO [04-01|13:55:25.450] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=10 static=0
ERROR[04-01|13:55:25.887] Invalid block total difficulty RLP       hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" err="rlp: non-canonical integer (leading zero bytes) for *big.Int"
INFO [04-01|13:55:25.887] Initialized state bloom                  items=3864442 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=10.553s
INFO [04-01|13:55:25.887] Deallocated state bloom                  items=3864442 errorrate=0.000
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x52a804]

goroutine 128 [running]:
math/big.(*Int).Cmp(0x400184f300, 0x0, 0x4a292b75ba73399a)
    math/big/int.go:328 +0x44
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*chainSyncer).nextSyncOp(0x4000bf8ba0, 0x400164bf28)
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/sync.go:264 +0x178
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*chainSyncer).loop(0x4000bf8ba0)
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/sync.go:210 +0x14c
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*handler).Start
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/handler.go:403 +0x188
```

It's maybe worth mentioning that nothing from the `dmesg -w` output points at anything indicating a failure with the SSD.

If I can be any more specific, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the storage was corrupted because an incorrect shutdown, or you found a bug. I'd suggest contacting the go-ethereum developers in their github repo for further assistance. Or perhaps delete everything and start from scratch again.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Ismael. I actually have deleted everything a few times but I eventually receive the same errors. I'll try the github repo for assistance.